On Frobenius–Schur indicator of real/complex representations
Let $G$ be a finite group with complex irreps $W_i$. Let $V$ be a real irrep of $G$. Denote $\chi_{W_i}$ and $\chi_{V}$ the corresponding characters.
Each $V$ has three possibilities:
Case 1: $\dim_{\mathbb{R}}\text{End}_G(V)=1$. In this case, there exists a complex irrep $W_i$ such that $V\otimes_{\mathbb{R}} \mathbb{C}=W_i$. Here, the Frobinus-Schur indicator of $W_i$ is 1.
Case 2: $\dim_{\mathbb{R}}\text{End}_G(V)=2$. In this case, there exist two non-isomorphic complex irreps $W_i$ and $W_j \cong W_i^*$ such that $V \otimes_{\mathbb{R}} \mathbb{C}=W_i \oplus W_j$. Here, the Frobinus-Schur indicator of $W_i$ and $W_j$ is 0.
Case 3: $\dim_{\mathbb{R}}\text{End}_G(V)=4$. In this case, there exists a complex irrep $W_i$ such that $V \otimes_{\mathbb{R}} \mathbb{C}=W_i \oplus W_i$. Here, the Frobinus-Schur indicator of $W_i$ is -1.
I have three questions: When we refer to real, complex, or quaternion-type irrep, do we mean irrep $W_i$ with Frobinus-Schur indicator 1, 0, or -1, respectively? Or do we mean irrep $V$ with $\dim_{\mathbb{R}}\text{End}_G(V)=$1, 2, or 4, respectively? Or do we mean both in different contexts?
Does real irrep $V$ have a Frobinus-Schur indicator? We know this number for complex irrep is $\frac{1}{|G|}\sum_{g \in G}\chi_{W_i}(g^2)$, do we have a similar version for $\frac{1}{|G|}\sum_{g \in G}\chi_{V}(g^2)$? ( I suspect we have Frobinus-Schur indicators 1, 0, or -2 for real irreps )
Is there any way that we can realize $\dim_{\mathbb{R}}\text{End}_G(V)$ using $\chi_V$?


It means both in different contexts, as far as I know. It's unfortunate but they can be disambiguated based on whether the author is discussing real or complex representations.

The Frobenius-Schur indicator makes sense over any ground field $K$ (although let's assume we're in the semisimple case that $\text{char}(K) \nmid |G|$), and over any ground field $K$ it is equal to $\dim S^2(V)^G - \dim \Lambda^2(V)^G$; you can see this on Wikipedia. These numbers tell you something about whether $V$ admits a nonzero invariant symmetric resp. skew-symmetric bilinear form, but if $G$ doesn't split over $K$ I don't know what the precise statements are.

For $V$ a real representation the orthogonality relations give $\dim_{\mathbb{R}} \text{End}_G(V) = \frac{1}{|G|} \sum_{g \in G} \chi_V(g)^2$.



Thanks a lot. Regarding my second question, do you mean the FS indicator is always 1 in real irreps? I am skeptical about this. For example if the real irrep $V$ is quaternion-type and $V \cong W_i \oplus W_i$, then $\chi_V=2\chi_{W_i}$; is that correct? If this is correct, then we have $\chi_{V}(g^2)=2\chi_{W_i}(g^2)$ and so the FS indicator of $V$ is -2. Am I missing something?

@khashayar: ah, okay, I misapplied the orthogonality relations here. I guess things are complicated; if $V$ is quaternionic then it looks like there's enough room for it to have both invariant symmetric bilinear forms and invariant skew-symmetric bilinear forms.

I am skeptical that even when $V$ is complex-type real irrep, we get a different FS indicator than 1. Here, $V \otimes \mathbb{C} \cong W_i \oplus W_i^*$ so $\chi_V=\chi_{W_i}+\bar{\chi}{W_i}$ so $\chi_V(g^2)=\chi{W_i}(g^2)+\bar{\chi}_{W_i}(g^2)$ for each $g$. Taking sum gives $0+0=0$. Am I right?

@khashayar: so if $V$ is complex type then it looks like it admits both an invariant symmetric bilinear form and an invariant skew-symmetric bilinear form, which I guess must be the real and complex parts of an invariant complex inner product on $V \otimes \mathbb{C}$ restricting to a real inner product on $V$. Those two cancel and that produces $0$.
